# erialport.list not a function. I have it when I try to connect to my Arduino

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino-uno

How can I decide a problem with my Arduino UNO? I have next mistake: serialport.list not a function. I have it when I try to connect to my Arduino by Node.js. This mistake in Johnny-Five libraries I think. Please. help me…(

Comment: you have to install the serialport module

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i installed serialport module.

Comment: My problem: I have Arduino module, led indicator. It's hard part. So. i have Node, and JavaScript code for control LED on Arduino. I want to connect to my Arduino module. I start Node, then i start LED script. In this moment i have mistakes: TypeError: serialport.list is not a function/ (((